# How to access dynamically added DOM element in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am implementing the required constraint through `$error`.
I want to access The input element inside the from. i.e. `{{frm.item.qid.$error.required}}`

But since the form Object contains attribute `q1` (value of `item.qid`), `frm.item` returns `null`.

So How can I access, lets say `frm.q1` (values for `item.qid` are  : q1,q2,q3, etc.) ?

Here's the code:

```
<li ng-repeat = "item in questions">
  <input name = {{item.qid}} type = "radio" ng-value = "item.option1" ng-model="item.selectedOption" required/>
  <label ng-bind = "item.option1"></label>
  <input name = {{item.qid}} type = "radio" ng-value = "item.option2" ng-model="item.selectedOption"/>
  <label ng-bind = "item.option2"></label>
  <input name = {{item.qid}} type = "radio" ng-value = "item.option3" ng-model="item.selectedOption"/>
  <label ng-bind = "item.option3"></label>
  <input name = {{item.qid}} type = "radio" ng-value = "item.option4" ng-model="item.selectedOption"/>
  <label ng-bind = "item.option4"></label>
  <label ng-show="">This is manadatory</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you print {{frm}} after your `ul li` in the DOM, you should see what's inside.

Comment: {"$error":{"required":[{"$viewValue":null,"$modelValue":null,"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"required":true},

Comment: First off, i dont know if this is your exact html, but you are missing double quotes around `{{item.qid}}`, should be `name ="{{item.qid}}"`